# Unordered_map constructed from initializer list with repeated keys

Tags: c++11, unordered-map, initializer-list

What does the standard guarantee will happen if an `unordered_map` (or more generally a unique associative container) is constructed with an `initializer_list` with repeated keys? Is it undefined or does it have unique compliant behavior? gcc 4.7 accepts code like this

```
 std::unordered_map<int, int> x = {{1,1}, {1,2}};
```

but that doesn't tell me what is guaranteed by the standard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "container requirements" state that `X(il)` is the "Same as `X(il.begin(),
il.end())`" (for an initializer list `il`), so the result is standardized and as expected, namelt, the elements are inserted in order.

Comment: Which leads to the first element being inserted and then replaced by the second?

Comment: Ah, ok. The Standard uses a quite vague formulation here: "Constructs an empty
container with an unspecified
number of buckets, using
`hasher()` as the hash function
and `key_equal()` as the key
equality predicate, and inserts
elements from `[i, j)` into it." (Table 103, `X a(i, j)`). That doesn't seem to say anything about the order of insertion :/